# Delete path that is longer than 256 characters using DirectoryInfo.Delete(true) method in c#

Tags: c#, .net, io

My Goal is to use Delete the entire folder and everything inside of that folder that is older than month. Following is code that i wrote:

```
foreach (String dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(args[0]))
{
    foreach (String subDir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(subDir);
        if (dirInfo.CreationTime < DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1))
        {
            try
            {
                dirInfo.Delete(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isssue: dirInfo.Delete(true) statement throws an exception when path is longer than 256 characters, and does not delete the folder. How can i over come that?
Thank you

Comment: [.NET 4.6.2 now has long path support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/), if upgrading is a possibility.

Comment: I actually just tried to change the Target Framework to : .NET framework 4.6.1. And it still does not work. I dont think i can install 4.6.2 unless you are positive that it will fix the issue.

Comment: It was fixed in 4.6.2, not 4.6.1. See the attached link I posted.

Comment: 4.6.2 is the first one to have long path support. If you don't want to or can't use 4.6.2 then you have to get 3rd party libraries such as [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core), or p/invoke into the native calls that have long path support. "unless you are positive that it will fix the issue" -- You have to test your own program, don't rely on others. Someone can easily say "yea, sure, I'm positive it will fix the issue", but it obviously doesn't mean your program won't blow up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try moving the folder first to a shorter directory path first so its path is no longer as long, and then deleting it.

```
dirInfo.MoveTo("C:\temp");
dirInfo.Delete(true);
```

Comment: Well that will only help if the path is so long, not if the filename is.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added another Catch block that catches DirectoryNotFoundException and in that catch block, I am using moveTo command and then try to delete. And it seems to work fine.
catch(DirectoryNotFoundException)
                                {
                                    dirInfo.MoveTo(@"c:\TempTCCleanUp");
                                    dirInfo.Delete(true);
                                }